# Drag and Drop, field made for the list while moving it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to bite it, problem is that when I add

```
style="list-style-type: none;"
```

to tag ul I have all the lists equal himself, but when I drag first list between third and fourth, It does not make room for the first list.  If I will remove liststyletype, then when i drag can be seen there is a place made for li, where I want place between lists rather than li

whole project

https://plnkr.co/edit/Hi9zUlvVyHWZdZVnk2Mp?p=preview

I use this directiv : 
https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists